# How to join/relate points to polygons by field

Tags: arcmap, attribute-joins, relates, cross-tabulation

I am using ArcMap with a basic license. I have a layer of polygon parcels and a layer of point turnouts. The turnouts deliver water to the parcel, **but are not located within the parcel**.

My parcels have a text field for the Turnout Unique ID, for example (2019,2020,3410). I spoke to an ESRI rep and they mentioned a relationship class tool that is available under a standard license. I want to be able to click on a parcel and the associated turnouts are shown. Is that the only tool to do this task?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise that you do an attribute join.
Assuming that both tables have **'Turnout Unique ID'**, right click on parcel in the table of content, click on Joins and Relates, and select Join
[image]
Use the following inputs:

1. Turnout Unique ID
2. Turnout points layer
3. Turnout Unique ID

[image]

if you want to keep the new joined table, you will have to export the feature class/ shapefile and give it a new name.

Comment: A join will result in the first turnout record only; subsequent turnout records will not be part of the output.  Alternatively, select the Relate option.  This will connect multiple turnouts to each polygon.